# CSV not showing up in responseObject

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, csv, curl, afnetworking-2

Rails server:

```
#via a POST

respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf { send_data ScheduleMachineReconciliationReport.to_pdf(@schedule_machine), type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline" }
        format.csv { send_data ScheduleMachineReconciliationReport.to_csv(@schedule_machine), type: "application/csv" }
      end
```

ScheduleMachineReconciliationReport.rb

```
  def to_csv
    csv_generation = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_header_titles
      products.each do |p|
        csv << write_product_array(p)
      end
    end

    puts "csv generation: " + csv_generation
    csv_generation
  end

def self.to_csv(schedule_machine)
    new(schedule_machine).to_csv
  end
```

server logs:

```
csv generation: Column,Products,Previous QTY,New QTY,QTY Sold,Slot Price,Expected Sales
2015-03-23T20:51:35.277019+00:00 app[web.1]: 9,Coke,0,0,0,3.00,0.00
```

Objective-C parsing:

```
  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

>>breakpoint        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@""];

po operation.responseString > nil
po responseObject > nil
```

EDIT:

cURLing does return a response in the command line.

Comment: does the respone show up if you perform the same HTTP call using curl on the command line or e.g. using Postman?

Comment: Yes, it does show up when I CURL.

Comment: I'm confused, are you generating the csv file from the data within `@schedule_machine`? Your `to_csv` method in ScheduleMachineReconciliationReport.rb doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: @KenStipek included the full initialization code

Answer (score 1):

I am not reproducing an issue.  I set up a Ruby on Rails app that simply echoes:

```
Column,Products,Previous QTY,New QTY,QTY Sold,Slot Price,Expected Sales
9,Coke,0,0,0,3.00,0.00
```

Using the following AFNetworking code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/test?format=csv"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc] init];
responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/csv", @"text/csv", nil];
operation.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

I see that the success block is executed, `responseObject` is not nil, and `operation.responseString` is the CSV string.

It might be a problem with the responseSerializer that you are using.

Comment: This looks right. But I don't have AFHTTPResponseSerializer. I guess that's in a later version. I'm going to update AFNetworking, but doing so right away breaks compatibility with RestKit. So I'm going to look at Mantle.. http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2012/1/4/yak-shaving

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can fix your issue, but at **[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-3)** says you must use a Mime type `text/csv`, and not `application/csv`.

I assume your server log shows what you expect (1 record with its columns headers).

Answer (score 0):

Content type can be also `application/x-csv`;`text/x-csv`;`application/csv`;`text/csv`.

So you need add them all:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/x-csv", @"text/x-csv", @"application/csv", @"text/csv", nil];
[manager GET:@"http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"CSV:\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:\n%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```